# Put font awesome icon in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, font-awesome

I have a navigation bar in javascript, which includes the titles of the links, but I want to put nice little icons next to the words. How can I embed the font awesome icons in the javascript?

A shortened version looks like

```
            ssSideNavSectionsProvider.initWithSections([{
            id: 'mainSection',
            name: 'Main',
            type: 'heading',
            children: [{
                id: 'home',
                name: 'Dashboard',
                state: 'common.home',
                type: 'link'
            }, {
                id: 'deviceLink',
                name: 'Devices',
                state: 'common.devices',
                type: 'link'
            }]}]);
```

And next to the word Dashboard I want a nice icon, for example the fa-dashboard icon.

Here's the HTML:
        < md-content flex role="navigation" ss-style-color="{'background-color': 'primary.default'}">
        
    < /md-content>

Comment: That all depends on what your HTML looks like. Handing us a data structure doesn't help at all.

Comment: then you'd need some html/css in there to switch to the appropriate font and supply the character you want. otherwise you're stuck embedding the byte sequence of that character, and hoping that the font used to display the word `Dashboard` contains that codepoint/symbol.

Comment: went ahead and added the html. I want to display a different icon for each title so I don't see how I could do this in HTML and also gave all the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Provided are you correctly loading the FontAwesome CSS file (either locally or from a CDN), then all you need to do is add `<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>` to the HTML where you want the icon to show up.

Replace `icon` with the actual name of the icon you want to use. For example, to show the "[arrows](http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrows/)" icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
```

List of all Font Awesome icons: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: But it's a navigation menu, and I want a different icon for each option. The HTML just grabs the whole menu, so I can't do it there

Comment: You will need to grab the HTML text somehow, insert the icon tags, and render this new HTML string. You can use a JavaScript library like jQuery to grab the HTML from an element: http://api.jquery.com/html/.